# How to write a Haskell functor instance for this custom data type?

Tags: haskell, functor

I am tasked with writing a functor instance for the MyList type defined below, leaving its original structure as is.

```
data MyList a = Elem a (MyList a) | Null (MyList a) | Done deriving Show
```

This is what I tried doing, but it gives a lot of errors.

```
instance Functor MyList where
  fmap f (Elem x xs) = Elem x xs
  fmap f (Null x) = Null x
  fmap f (Done) = Done
```

Errors:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> MyList a -> MyList b
    at Main.hs:66:3-6
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> MyList a -> MyList b
    at Main.hs:66:3-6
  Expected type: MyList b
    Actual type: MyList a
• In the expression: Elem x xs
  In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (Elem x xs) = Elem x xs
  In the instance declaration for ‘Functor MyList’
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: MyList a (bound at Main.hs:66:18)
    x :: a (bound at Main.hs:66:16)
    f :: a -> b (bound at Main.hs:66:8)
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> MyList a -> MyList b (bound at Main.hs:66:3)
```

Comment: I could just give the answer but I feel a simple hint will help you see yourself how to fix it: you're currently not using the function `f` at all in the result

Comment: My advice: if you run into trouble, try more obvious examples first, so you collect experience. Or look at other instances of Functor from Haskell source code.

Comment: Is there a reason for separate `Elem` and `Null` constructors, instead of a single `Foo (Maybe a) (MyList a)` constructor? (For that matter, is there any significant difference between `Null []` and `Done`?)

Comment: A hint: in `fmap f (Elem x xs) = Elem x xs` we have `x :: a` and `xs :: MyList a`. In the right hand side, we want to have type `b` instead of `a`. Luckily, we have a function `f :: a->b`, so...